# How can I send UIImage to Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to send to my Firestore database without saving this image to photos? I see how Firestore wants a reference to it and the only way is to pick a photo from photos. With my app, I feel like that is redundant to ask for permission for their photos, as I just want to send a photo that is taken straight into the database.

Comment: Saving `UIImage` objects to Firestore Cloud?  Have you read its documentation to find out what type of data types you can store with it?

Comment: You should use Firestore Storage if you want to store `UIImage` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you definitely can save a picture that is taken from the camera straight to your database without having to ask permission for photo gallery access.

I'll give you a code example below:

```
    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer!, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer!)

        //set the picture taken as UIImage just in case you'd like to preview the image before saving it
        //let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(yourPictureName).jpg")
            guard let data = imageData else { return }
            storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil){ (metadata, error) in
                guard metadata != nil else {
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }

                    // save this URL to your database as usual

                })
            }
     }
```

Comment: Why convert `imageData` to a `UIImage` and then convert the `UIImage` back to `Data`? Just send `imageData`.

Comment: guard let data = image.jpeg else { return }  
I get the error : Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'jpeg'

Comment: @JohnCena Look at the reference documentation for UIImage and you will see the proper name of the function to get the JPEG data.

Comment: @JohnCena use this instead `guard let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }`